# Does raster intersect polygon in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder

In ArcMap, I'm building a model which is iterating over ArcGrid rasters. I only want the steps to run where the raster intersects with a certain polygon. How do I add this condition to ModelBuilder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a mosaic with all the rasters I had, and using the "Select Layer By Location" tool in "Data Management Tools">"Layers and Table Views". You can't select the raster layer, but you can select the footprint of the raster.